# MeeGo Handset Emulator not starting on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, emulation, qt-creator, meego

I am trying my hands on the MeeGo and I have downloaded the `MeeGo 1.1 SDK for Windows` and followed everything step by step given in the [`MeeGo wiki`](http://wiki.meego.com/SDK/Docs/1.1/Getting_started_with_the_MeeGo_SDK_for_Windows) to install SDK on my Windows 7 System and everything was fine. But when I start the emulator from the `Qt Creator IDE or MADDE terminal` the emulator screens appears and nothing happens after a startup welcome message as given in below image.

[image]

My System configurtion are as follows:

> Operating System : Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit
>
> Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6500@2.10 GHz

I have also refered the [thread](http://forum.meego.com/showthread.php?p=18357) on the MeeGo developer site but seems this is not a workaround of for my problem. I know this SDK is in beta version but as far as many developers are using it on Windows system, so I don't know if there is something  wrong with my emulator.

Kindly post your valueable feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the problem. The MeeGo emulator runs on KQEMU and it could only be used on 32-bit Windows. Though I have 32-bit version Windows installed but I have checked the CPU information on the Intel's official site and indeed the processor [Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6500@2.10 GHz](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=39311) has 64-bit instruction set. That's why this is not running.