# How to initiate MeeGo AppDev?

Tags: windows, qt, nokia, intel, meego

I need to know following things.

- What kind of programming languages are being used for MeeGo OS for phone ?
- How many Phone does support MeeGo till now ?
- How many operating system does support MeeGo SDK Setup?
- What are the system requirements for the MeeGo SDK over Windows?
- What kind of softwares do I need to install over windows ?

I have already downloaded MeeGo SDK over a laptop & I have no idea about it. I know it requires attension to understand the whole things. What I need is Quick References. Just because I have already spent 2 days for researching & I installed to many different different things. First I tried to setup everything on a UBANTU machine & after a day my project manager alloted that PC to other Guy. Now, They provide me different machine. I redownloaded everything for windows now. First I downloaded "MeeGo SDK 1.2 Preview", Then I downloaded "MeeGo SDK 1.1". Then I downloaded "qt-win-opensource-4.7.2-vs2008". Then Again downloaded "qemu-0.9.0-windows". Now, I am going crazy. What to do now? What to do to just run "Hello world" ? My Project manager is frequently asking for a sample project ( even though I am already invovled in iPhone App Dev for 2-3 apps ). Need Some Help, here.
Where to initiate? What are the foolProof steps for HelloWorld ?

Comment: The only Meego phone that I know of is the N950, and that hasn't even been released yet!

Comment: @Robin Green: Yep, but now it's announced as Developer Device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534074/best-resources-to-learn-programming-for-meego)  [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146152/meego-handset-emulator-not-starting-on-windows-7) even if its Nokia N950 is not released...